# Webpack2: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I get this error in app.js:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Why webpack require not work? Is any additional wabpack configutarion needed to make this work?

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry:  ['./src/app.js', './src/styles/styles.scss'],
  output: {
    filename: 'dist/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { // regular css files
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          loader: 'css-loader?importLoaders=1',
        }),
      },
      { // sass / scss loader for webpack
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
      },
      {
        test: /\.hbs$/,
        loader: 'handlebars-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ // define where to save the file
      filename: 'dist/[name].bundle.css',
      allChunks: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

**app.js**

```
const something = require("./something.js");
```

Comment: Why do you need to `require('webpack')`? If you want to use it like a script on a web page, then you do it wrong, because webpack is a node.js script and should be launched as `webpack -p --other-args` on command line (depends on how you installed it). Try following ["Get started" article](https://webpack.js.org/guides/get-started/).